# Differences between two linq query result

Tags: c#, linq

I want to learn why these two queries return different results.

This query returns 6:

```
var a = (from belg in contextArchive.Belgeler
         join zrf in contextArchive.Zarflar on belg.Parent_ID equals zrf.ID
         where belg.RefETTN == this.BelgeETTN
         select new { zrf }).Count();
```

While this query returns 3:

```
var b = (from belg in contextArchive.Belgeler
         join zrf in contextArchive.Zarflar on belg.Parent_ID equals zrf.ID
         where belg.RefETTN == this.BelgeETTN
         select new { zrf }).ToList();

countKabulRed = b.Count();
```

Comment: What SQL queries they are generating? If it's MSSQL then you can check SQL Profiler to get queries. From the first look first query will be executed on SQL side. Second one on backend side. Maybe SQL queries are different somehow

Comment: Is this going to a DBMS of some sort? If so have you looked at the SQL each call generates, that should reveal something.

Comment: If you can see these two query same i think it will related with using join

Comment: It really boils down to what contextArchive.Belgeler is. As we don't know the linq provider used, we cannot really help you. Even though I cannot think of any sane provider that would give different results here.

Comment: I am using linq provider and that provider same for two query. You can trust me

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some null values in `b`. The different between `a` and `b` is that `a` uses SQL's COUNT that neglects null values, while `b`'s `Count()` includes both null and non-null values.

Comment: yes that's true b has some null values. How can i fix this to return 3 for first query ?